# delete rows from table after delete row from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this schema:

[image: table schema]

What I want to do is that, after delete a row in `word`/`palabra`, all rows in `article`/`articulo` that had a reference to it will be deleted as well.

Note that is a `n to n` relationship, so the table `r1` contains all the foreign keys.

Comment: You can define a trigger.

Comment: Why not enable cascade delete when defining foreign key?

Comment: @dev8080 I have enabled cascade delete, but as I say before, it will only delete the "word" row and the "r1" row BUT table "article" is not affected...

Comment: @inarilo How a trigger is defined in this case?

Comment: it depends on your dbms. but basically after delete of word, delete all the connected articles.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Postgres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Original answer had the wrong assumption. Here is the new answer:

To have the article rows get deleted, you can use a trigger. This will run before your foreign key constraint cascade delete because of the "BEFORE DELETE" subclause.

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_delete_word_trigger
    BEFORE DELETE ON word
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM article
    WHERE article.id_article IN
      (SELECT DISTINCT id_article FROM R1 where R1.id_word = deleted.id_word)
END;
```

[More on triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html)

---

Old answer:

Other information for the cascade delete:

You can use the "ON DELETE" subclause in  the foreign key constraint to trigger a behavior on the relationship table.

```
CREATE TABLE R1
(
  id_r1 serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  id_article int NOT NULL,
  id_word int NOT NULL,

  CONSTRAINT fk_r1_word
    FOREIGN KEY (id_word)
    REFERENCES words (id_word)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,

  CONSTRAINT fk_r1_article
    FOREIGN KEY (id_article)
    REFERENCES articles (id_article)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

"ON DELETE CASCADE" allows your relationship table to clean up after itself when something it is pointing to is deleted. This way your articles always have their words removed when the source of the word is deleted, and all the word relationship data associated with the article is deleted if the article is deleted, assuming that is desired. None of the rows in word or article tables are affected if a relationship is deleted.

There are other options available to set up automatic behaviors when foreign rows are changed/deleted. Here is [some info](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) on this subject for MySQL.

Comment: I have done exactly this, (I mean before you post it) when a "word" is deleted it the r1 reference also is deleted whit this code. But the "article" that was being referenced in the r1 will remain...I need to delete it also

Comment: I have updated the beginning of my response to include the deletion of articles.